# Regular expression for a DFA that accepts the empty string as well as other strings

Tags: regex, finite-automata, dfa, nfa

For the following <s>DFA</s> NFA

[image]

I produced the RE

```
(a + b)(ab)*
```

However, I then realised that my RE doesn't accept the empty string as it only accepts strings beginning with an `a` or a `b`, yet the <s>DFA</s> NFA also accepts the empty string as the initial state is an accepting state.

What is a valid RE for this <s>DFA</s> NFA? I would think something along the lines of

```
Ø + (a + b)(ab).*
```

but I doubt this syntax is accepted.

**EDIT**

I have also just realised that the example I have made is an NFA, but that is besides the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

(a + b)* would be the answer of what you mentioned in the question title. With an *, it means you can have empty string. a+b means you can choose either a or b. So finally you can choose a or b repeatedly.

Comment: But `(a+b)*` would accept the string `aaa`, but the NFA wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following expression?

```
^(|[ab](ab)*)$
```

This accepts either an empty string, or a sequence of none or more times `ab`, preceded by an `a` or `b`.

But it depends on the exact regular expression dialect if this solves your problem.

Comment: "... or more times" - take one time: `ab`. This string is not accepted by the NFA. `a` goes from `P0` to `P1`, but `b` is not defined on `P1`.

Comment: @KOB Better? Probably not the formal regular expression the OP seems to be looking for, though.